# Interpolation between components of a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation, indexing

In a project that I am doing I need to reach floating indexed elements of a matrix. That is to say for instance I want to reach the (16.25,1) th element of a matrix. That might seem odd at the first glance. However, by (16.25,1), I mean the interpolation between (16,1) and (17,1) with weights of .25 and .75 respectively.

Is there a built-in function for that?

Many thanks,
Safak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html):

```
Z = randi(10,10); % 10 x 10 random matrix with integers from 1 to 10
Z(1:2,1:2)
%ans =
%   2   4
%   7   6

% use interp2 to interpolate at row 1.5, col 2
z = interp2(Z,1.5,2)
% z = 6.5000
```

Comment: This method is only good if you have a square matrix. What if the matrix is not square?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2-D interpolation:

```
ZI = interp2(Z,XI,YI) assumes that X = 1:n and Y = 1:m, where [m,n] = size(Z)
```

where `Z` is your matrix, and `XI` & `YI` are your fractional indices.